# How to navigate the page automatically in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, settimeout

I have two html pages:

1. flash.html
2. main.html

in this i want to load **flash.html** page first for 5 seconds and then automatically the **main.html** have to load how to do this ?

i have tried with  `setTimeout(function(){ SplashBeGone(); }, 5000);`

But i am not getting the answer can anyone help me ?

Comment: You can use iframe for this and after 5 second change `src` value of iframe using `setTimeout` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is in `SplashBeGone()`?

I would assume you would do something like;

```
setTimeout( function(){window.location.href = "main.html"},5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use meta refresh for that:
http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

Comment: It's best not to use Javascript for things like this, as it might be disabled.  This is much better than using JavaScript, wherever possible.

Answer (score 1):

put this on your `flash.html` on the `<head>` area

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL='main.html '">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this way

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     setInterval(function() { //even setTimeout can be used
      window.location.replace("main.html"); // redirect to main.html after 5 seconds
    }, 5000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Don't forget to import jQuery to use this solution

Answer (score 0):

add meta refresh in the head of **flash.html**

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL='main.html'">
    ...
</head>
```

it's much more better than using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do is without `Javascript` or `jQuery`. You can simply use `HTML Meta` Tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=main.html" />
```

or full url

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://www.example.com/main.html" />
```

you can learn more about how to use meta refresh here: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

It works on all the `browsers` even on `mobile browsers` without `javascript`

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use this function

> > `window.onload = function()
> >
> >         {
> >
> >               setInterval(function() {
> >
> >               window.location.replace("main.html");}, 5000);
> >
> >         }`